# Puseaudio Equalizer not working in 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, equalizer

when Running from terminal with `qpaeq` it show like this :

[image: Terminal Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Try installing said packages :

```
sudo apt install dbus-python qt4
```

Then trying running pulseaudio.

Comment: all dependencies are meet and installed already , including module are there loaded in `/etc/pulse/default.qa`

Answer (score 1):

a better package and solution i have found for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or higher , rather than pyqt4 things and some other issues of pulseaudio-equalizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y

sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio
```

which installed all including pulseaudio equalizer etc etc

and as I am using KUBUNTU 18.04 so i have additionally updated my '~/.zshrc' ( others can add this to '~/.bashrc' if you have bash as default shell ) with adding this line to the end in '.zshrc' :

```
pactl unload-module module-device-manager > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**OR**

Simple from terminal :

For bashrc `echo "pactl unload-module module-device-manager > /dev/null 2>&1" >> ~/.bashrc`

For zshrc `echo "pactl unload-module module-device-manager > /dev/null 2>&1" >> ~/.zshrc`

Now everything working as i wanted

Installed packages with pulseaudio-equalizer and others Log [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH20d.png)

.zshrc added with a new line [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHhqO.png)

It works now [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJYiu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with qpaeq after installing Anaconda. The solution was to change  PATH environment variable moving '~/anaconda3/bin' at the end of PATH content before to export it. It looks like there were incompatibilities between dbus/qt4 installed by anaconda and the original python.